# Libgdx: Eliminate transparency artifacts when using CameraGroupStrategy with DecalBatch

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I was wondering, is there any way to remove artifacts from the CameraGroupStrategy when having multiple texture regions overlapping with transparency. Is there another group strategy that i can use with perspective camera or can someone suggest a shader that I can use or a whole new group strategy? Please. Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about Z-fighting? Are these decals that are in the exact same place in 3D?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same y plane in 3d. I have multiple texture regions with transparency overlapping. And the point of overlap where there is transparency, shows transparency, but not of the texture region it is overlapping with.

Comment: OK. You probably got down voted because your question is vague without that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they are in the exact same space in 3D, reducing your camera's depth won't help. You will need to turn off depth testing. The downside is that your decals cannot be automatically obscured by 3D models in your scene. And you must sort them properly if they are opaque (translucent decals have to be sorted anyway). Make your own class and copy all of CameraGroupStrategy's code into it. Remove the line

```
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

from the `beforeGroups` method.

The other tricky part will be sorting them. Decals need to be sorted from far to near if depth testing is turned off (which it already is for blended decals in CameraGroupStrategy), but your decals that are in the same place may not consistently sort in the same order as the camera moves, which will cause flickering as they are drawn in various different orders.

You might want to completely remove the Sorter from this class and the call to `contents.sort(cameraSorter)`. And then take pains to submit your decals in a consistent order, putting farther away groups of decals first, but keeping them in their same order if they are in the same plane.

Or, you could subclass Decal to add an extra int parameter, and call it for example `planePosition`. Then your sorter could try to detect very close decals and defer to their `planePosition` if it thinks they are very close. Something like this:

```
    sorter = new Comparator<Decal>() {
        @Override
        public int compare (Decal o1, Decal o2) {
            float dist1 = camera.position.dst(o1.position);
            float dist2 = camera.position.dst(o2.position);
            float diff = dist2 - dist1;
            if (o1 instanceof MyDecal && o2 instanceof MyDecal && Math.abs(diff) < 0.001f)
                return (int)Math.signum(((MyDecal)o2).planePosition - ((MyDecal)o1).planePosition);
            return (int)Math.signum(diff);
        }
    }
```

If you are also using this for opaque decals that might be coplanar, then you need to also need to sort them, since depth testing is off. And note that they will be doing overdraw on each other since there is no depth testing, which may have a performance impact.

Comment: Thank you. This sounds perfectly reasonable. I'll give it a shot :)